# Woocommerce - How to add one link "add to cart" to the loop product thumbnail?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried several things adding the code to functions.php.

I think that the time I've been closer was with this code:

```
   printf('<a class="button" href=" ..... "?>');
    echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail(); 
    printf('</a>');
    
}
```

But I don't know what to href on there.

- previously, I removed the other liks with:

```
/*remove links to loop, add link to title*/
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10);
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5);
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 5);
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 20);
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
    echo sprintf('<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><a title="%2$s" href="%1$s">%2$s</a></h2>',
        get_the_permalink(),
        get_the_title()
    );
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Hello, Are you asking how to place an add to cart link on the thumbnail of a product?

Comment: Hi Rudy, exactly. On the thumbnail, one link to "add to cart". I have the cart as external product so I'd wish it on there too.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some modifications that need to be made for it to fit your scenario.

Add the following code to your functions.php file.

This will only add the link to the thumbnail if you are on the products page.

```
function add_link_woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html( $html, $post_thumbnail_id ) {

    /**
     * This will only add the link on a single product page.
     */
    if ( is_product() ) :
        global $product;
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        $product_url = get_permalink( $product_id );
        $main_image = true;
        $flexslider        = (bool) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled', get_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' ) );
        $gallery_thumbnail = wc_get_image_size( 'gallery_thumbnail' );
        $thumbnail_size    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', array( $gallery_thumbnail['width'], $gallery_thumbnail['height'] ) );
        $image_size        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_image_size', $flexslider || $main_image ? 'woocommerce_single' : $thumbnail_size );
        $full_size         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'full' ) );
        $thumbnail_src     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, $thumbnail_size );
        $full_src          = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, $full_size );
        $alt_text          = trim( wp_strip_all_tags( get_post_meta( $post_thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ) ) );
        $image             = wp_get_attachment_image(
            $post_thumbnail_id,
            $image_size,
            false,
            apply_filters(
                'woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params',
                array(
                    'title'                   => _wp_specialchars( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_thumbnail_id ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true ),
                    'data-caption'            => _wp_specialchars( get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $post_thumbnail_id ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true ),
                    'data-src'                => esc_url( $full_src[0] ),
                    'data-large_image'        => esc_url( $full_src[0] ),
                    'data-large_image_width'  => esc_attr( $full_src[1] ),
                    'data-large_image_height' => esc_attr( $full_src[2] ),
                    'class'                   => esc_attr( $main_image ? 'wp-post-image' : '' ),
                ),
                $post_thumbnail_id,
                $image_size,
                $main_image
            )
        );
        $html = '<div data-thumb="' . esc_url( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '" data-thumb-alt="' . esc_attr( $alt_text ) . '" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="' . esc_url( $product_url ) . '/?add-to-cart=' . $product_id .  '">' . $image . '</a></div>';

        return $html;
    endif; 

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'add_link_woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 10, 2 );
```